# rabbitmq remain so many unacked messages when using federation

Tags: python, rabbitmq, federation

I'm using rabbitmq federation to transfer messages to a remote server, and remote server will also send messages back to my local server. However, I find that there are so many unacked messages in my local server federation queue, seems like the remote consumers ack so slow.

The queue is :
federation: remote -> rabbit@remotehost

unacked messages in this queue is increasing, and the service in remote server is not working properly.

I'm using python pika, when there are just a single thread to send messages to remote, it's working, but will soon remains so many unacked messages when the thread and process increase.